# Fundamental Lemma for variational calculus for measurable function

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Suppose I am given a function $f$ which is integrable. Is it possible to formulate the following Fundamental Lemma for Variational Calculus?

If for all measurable integrable function $\phi$ and a integrable function $f$:$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\phi(x)dx=0$$, then $f=0$ a.e..

My suggestion to proof this is, if $f\neq0$, then there exist a measurable set $A$ such that $f>0$. Taking the characteristic function $1_{A}$, which is clearly measurable, then $$\int_Af(x)dx>0$$ which is a contradiction.

Is this correct? Do I need the boundedness of the set $A$?

Comment: If the set $A$ has measure zero then $\int_A f=0$

Comment: $\phi$ is just any measurable function or has also other properties..because in the general theorem we have compaclty supported smooth functions

Comment: @MariosGretsas No, I want to consider a more general class of function as my variational problem does not depend on any derivative. As the class of compactly supported smooth function is smaller. I thought it would hold for such a large class.

Comment: if $f$ is integrable the you can use the continuous functions with compact support which are dense in the $L^p$ spaces.You will prove that $f=0$ almost everywhere..clearly this is a larger class of functions

Comment: @MariosGretsas Why I can't just use some measurable functions? I mean this is even larger. Only problem would occur if we are considering smaller class of function isn't it? I don't assume that my solution to the variational problem might be continuous.

Comment: when you say $f=0$ you mean zero everywhere or almost everywhere ?

Comment: @MariosGretsas Sorry I mean almost everywhere.

Comment: @MariosGretsas Yes for sure you can find counter examples. I mean my assupmtion is  for all $\phi$. If we fix the f(x) as you have provided, we can still find a $\phi$ such that the integral is non zero. So it doesn't hold for all $\phi$

Comment: Your preconditions seem much stronger than necessary. For any integrable $f : \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ and any set $A$ of finite measure, consider $$\phi_A(x) = \operatorname{sgn}(f(x))\cdot 1_A(x)$$ Then $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\phi_A(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_A \lvert f\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x$$ so if this integral is $0$, then $f = 0$ a.e. on $A$. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as a union of countably many $A$, and the countable union of null sets is null, $f = 0$ a.e. on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @MichaelLee Which part do you mean? that A should be bounded? So it is sufficient for requiring A with a finite measure?

Comment: I mean requiring that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 0$ for _all_ integrable $\phi$. There are much smaller classes of functions $\phi$ that will imply $f = 0$ a.e.